# How to select rows in Pandas dataframe based on string matching in multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I don't think this *exact* question has been answered yet, so here goes.

I have a Pandas data frame, and I want to select all rows that contain a string in column A *or* column B.

Say the dataframe looks like this:

```
d = {'id':["1", "2", "3", "4"], 
     'title': ["Horses are good", "Cats are bad", "Frogs are nice", "Turkeys are the best"], 
     'description':["Horse epitome", "Cats bad but horses good", "Frog fancier", "Turkey tome, not about horses"],
     'tags':["horse, cat, frog, turkey", "horse, cat, frog, turkey", "horse, cat, frog, turkey", "horse, cat, frog, turkey"],
     'date':["2019-01-01", "2019-10-01", "2018-08-14", "2016-11-29"]}

dataframe  = pandas.DataFrame(d)
```

Which gives:

```
id              title                      description               tag           date
1   "Horses are good"                  "Horse epitome"       "horse, cat"    2019-01-01
2      "Cats are bad"                       "Cats bad"       "horse, cat"    2019-10-01
3    "Frogs are nice"      "Frog fancier, horses good"      "horse, frog"    2018-08-14
4   "Turkey are best"                    "Turkey tome"    "turkey, horse"    2016-11-29
```

Let's say I want to create a new dataframe containing rows with the string `horse` (ignoring capitalisation) in the column `title` OR the column `description`, but not in the column `tag` (or any other column).

The result should be (row 2 and 4 get dropped):

```
id                title                     description                 tag          date  
1     "Horses are good"                  "Horse epitome"       "horse, cat"    2019-01-01
3      "Frogs are nice"      "Frog fancier, horses good"      "horse, frog"    2018-08-14
```

I have seen a few answers for one column, such as something like:

```
dataframe[dataframe['title'].str.contains('horse')]
```

But I am not sure (1) how to add multiple columns to this statement and (2) how to modify it with something like `string.lower()` to remove capitals in the column values for the string match.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If want specify columns for test one possible solution is join all columns and then test with [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and `case=False`:

```
s = dataframe['title'] + dataframe['description']
df = dataframe[s.str.contains('horse', case=False)]
```

Or create conditions for each column and chain them by bitwise `OR` with `|`:

```
df = dataframe[dataframe['title'].str.contains('horse', case=False) | 
               dataframe['description'].str.contains('horse', case=False)]
```

Also if want specify column column for not test chain solution with bitwise `AND` with invert condition by `~` for `NOT MATCH`:

```
df = dataframe[s.str.contains('horse', case=False) &
               ~dataframe['tags'].str.contains('horse', case=False)]
```

For second solution add `()` around all columns with chained by `OR`:

```
df = dataframe[(dataframe['title'].str.contains('horse', case=False) | 
               dataframe['description'].str.contains('horse', case=False)) &
              ~dataframe['tags'].str.contains('horse', case=False)]]
```

EDIT:

Like @WeNYoBen commented you can add [`DataFrame.copy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to end for prevent [SettingWithCopyWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) like:

```
s = dataframe['title'] + dataframe['description']
df = dataframe[s.str.contains('horse', case=False)].copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "logical or" operator `|` on the series corresponding to each column:

```
filtered = df[df['title'].str.contains('horse', case=False) | 
              df['description'].str.contains('horse', case=False)]
```

If you have many columns, you could use a reduce operation:

```
import functools
import operator

colnames = ['title', 'description']
mask = functools.reduce(operator.or_, (df[col].str.contains('horse', case=False) for col in colnames))
filtered = df[mask]
```

Comment: Please remove first solution, because in my answer.